# web3 js pass array of structure

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have method in my contract

```
{
    "inputs": [
      {
        "internalType": "uint256",
        "name": "_someId",
        "type": "uint256"
      },
      {
        "internalType": "uint256",
        "name": "_timeExp",
        "type": "uint256"
      },
      {
        "internalType": "uint256",
        "name": "_timeDeadLine",
        "type": "uint256"
      },
      {
        "internalType": "string",
        "name": "_Symbol",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "components": [
          {
            "internalType": "enum Actions",
            "name": "compare",
            "type": "uint8"
          },
          {
            "internalType": "int256",
            "name": "value",
            "type": "int256"
          },
          {
            "internalType": "int256",
            "name": "raise",
            "type": "int256"
          },
          {
            "internalType": "uint256",
            "name": "bet",
            "type": "uint256"
          },
          {
            "internalType": "bool",
            "name": "isWin",
            "type": "bool"
          }
        ],
        "internalType": "struct Outcome[2]",
        "name": "_outcomes",
        "type": "tuple[2]"
      }
    ],
    "name": "makeSchedule",
    "outputs": [],
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
  },
```

How can I pass `_outcomes` ?
I try like this , but have error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: param.map is not a function

```
 [
        [1,4815087599255,0,0,false],
        [4,4815087599255,0,0,false]
    ]
```

Comment: Can you include the actual contract?

Comment: @JulissaDC what do you mean? I add code of function in my contract (ABI file)

Comment: I mean the actual code where you do `function makeSchedule` etc

Comment: @JulissaDC  this my code

`const gas=await tokenInstance.methods.makeSchedule(0,1638793499935,1638914400000,'BTC/USD',[[1,4815087599255,0,0,!1],[4,4815087599255,0,0,!1]]).estimateGas({from:account}).then((response:any)=>{response.toString()}).catch((error:any)=>{console.log(error);return 0})`

Comment: Where are you calling `param.map`?

Comment: @JulissaDC web3js call `param.map` when try to encode to ABI

Comment: @Alexander Were you able to solve this?